# Can someone find out how this dplyr table doesn't work?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have to make a table in which the mean and median from the logsales per month are set out from the "txhousing" dataset. The exercise i got is the following: “The table below show the means and medians of the log of sales per month, sorted by mean”

- Insert a new r chunk and type the code in it to display that table
- Use na.omit to get rid of cases with missing values
- Use the dplyr command mutate to make the variable logsales
- Use the dplyr command group_by to group by month
- Use the dplyr command summarise to display the table
- Use the dplyr command arrange to sorth by mean
- Connect the commands with the pipe operator %>%

I've tried to mix up the code multiple times but I can't find out why it keeps on giving me NA's in my table.

```
library(tidyverse)
summary(txhousing)    
na.omit(txhousing)    
txhousing<- as.data.frame(txhousing)
logsales <- log(txhousing$sales)  
group_by(txhousing, txhousing$month)   
txhousing<- txhousing %>% mutate(logsales= log(txhousing$sales))    
txhousing %>% group_by(txhousing$month) %>% summarise(mean(logsales), median(logsales)) %>% arrange(mean)
```

I expect to get a table with the mean and median of the logsales per month, but what i get is only NA in the column from the mean en the median and the arrange gives the following error:

> Error: cannot arrange column of class 'function' at position 1`

Answer (score 0):

There are `NA` values in the columns, so you need to tell `mean` and `median` to ignore them. And also name the columns in `summarise` to use `arrange` on column named as `mean`.

```
txhousing %>% 
  group_by(txhousing$month) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(logsales, na.rm = T), 
            med= median(logsales, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  arrange(mean) %>%
  rename(month = `txhousing$month`)
```

This creates following `tibble`

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   month  mean   med
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  4.95  4.74
 2     2  5.13  4.93
 3    11  5.19  4.96
 4    12  5.24  5.02
 5    10  5.29  5.08
 6     9  5.32  5.09
 7     3  5.38  5.15
 8     4  5.42  5.21
 9     5  5.52  5.29
10     7  5.53  5.30
11     8  5.53  5.33
12     6  5.56  5.34
```